# shema.org structured data type for driving instructor or other learning center

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

Trying to find a proper type of structured data for driving school/driving instructor. According Google recommendations "Use the most specific LocalBusiness sub-type possible; for example, Restaurant, DaySpa, HealthClub, and so on."

Looking at [LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness#subtypes) sub-types
More specific Types
AnimalShelter
ArchiveOrganization
AutomotiveBusiness
ChildCare
Dentist
DryCleaningOrLaundry
EmergencyService
...

there is nothing related [AutomotiveBusiness](https://schema.org/AutomotiveBusiness#subtypes) maybe can be used, but its sub-types are more related to the machinery, but not the education side.

Looking at Organization branch, there is [EducationalOrganization](https://schema.org/EducationalOrganization#subtypes), but there is nothing for additional learning courses

Any suggestions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SEO is off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semantics of a hierarchical structure with **[HTML heading elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)** for your web page, the content of which your business represents can help.
The most important element such as H1 represents the subject of the content, which in your case is the name of your business.
This business of yours offers services such as driving courses. The name of these courses can be specified as the content of element H2 or H3, if element H2 is already in the content, for example, it can be something similar to "Our services or offers".
Based on such a hierarchical structure, you can create your structured data and this will meet **[Google's requirement](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#relevance)**:

> **Relevance**
>
> Your structured data should be a true representation of the
> page content.

Thus, it might make sense to set your top-level type such as LocalBusiness, and specify the business name, legal business name, business description, and other properties that you can find in the Schema and **[Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business)** documentation.

To specify your courses, you can use the **[makesOffer](https://schema.org/makesOffer)** property and embed the **[Offer](https://schema.org/Offer)** type to this property, which in turn has an **[itemOffered](https://schema.org/itemOffered)** property in which you can nest the **[Course](https://schema.org/Course)** type. This can be a good solution for a list of your courses, which you can represent in structured data as an array.
Also, you can use **[subjectOf](https://schema.org/subjectOf)** property for **Course** type embed.
In turn, the Course type has the property such as **[provider](https://schema.org/provider)** in which you can set the name of your business and this will create a reciprocal link between your business and the course (s) that the business offers, i.e. create linked data.

If the page content has a call to action, then you might consider embed the **[OrganizeAction](https://schema.org/OrganizeAction)** type in the **potentialAction** property.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is something I will consider and investigate further.